# Vaadin7 video exception

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

Sometimes, I get the following exception when using the "Video" component:

```
May 24, 2021 1:20:32 PM com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler doDefault
SEVERE: 
org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.completeWrite(WriteFlusher.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$3.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:262)
    ... 11 more
```

A similar error seems to happen under Tomcat, but it has far more information related to Vaadin directly.  I cannot prove they are the same error because of the sparsity of information provided by Jetty, but they do happen in similar situations.

```
[2021-05-24 13:39:15 EDT] INFO org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke [2021-05-24 13:39:15 EDT] SEVERE com.mobiwms.website.WmsUI$1 error Uncaught exception
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:356)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.appendByteArray(OutputBuffer.java:795)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.append(OutputBuffer.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:391)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:369)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:96)
    at com.vaadin.server.DownloadStream.writeResponse(DownloadStream.java:307)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractMedia.handleConnectorRequest(AbstractMedia.java:129)
    at com.vaadin.server.ConnectorResourceHandler.handleRequest(ConnectorResourceHandler.java:90)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1435)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:380)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.flush(SecureNioChannel.java:144)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.write(SecureNioChannel.java:654)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:157)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1306)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:726)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.writeBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.write(SocketWrapperBase.java:434)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:623)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityOutputFilter.doWrite(IdentityOutputFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:225)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:351)
    ... 34 more
```

How do I prevent this problem?  If I knew what to wrap in `try...catch`, I would do that, but I am not entirely sure what to wrap.  It is very random.  I know I can trigger it if I open and close the video multiple times in a row, rather quickly.  From what I have seen online, it might be related to some timeout, but the randomness confuses me.  Sometimes I don't get the error, sometimes I do, whether auto-play is on or off.  I cannot see a reliable pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The exception happens when the connection is broken while server is writing file (here video stream) to the Browser. Apparently Browser was not gracefully closed or proxy disconnected it.

Comment: But how do I solve it?  Maybe wait for video to be fully written before allowing user to close window?  But how do I wait for this to finish?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really like this answer, but it seems to band-aide the situation.  If people have a better solution, please tell me.  Anyway, basically, since handleConnectorRequest is noticing the problem, I figure I can get around the error by ignoring the exception.

```
        helpVideo = new Video() {

            @Override
            public boolean handleConnectorRequest(VaadinRequest request, VaadinResponse response, String path)
                    throws IOException {
                
                try {
                    return super.handleConnectorRequest(request, response, path);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    LOGGER.severe("Exception with video: " + e);
                }
                
                // This is not ideal, but we are sort of faking that things worked to get around other issues
                return true;
            }
            
        };
```

Yes, while perfectly legal, this seems like a terrible idea.  But it works, so I offer it as a workaround for people who have the same issue.

Comment: In theory logging error or warning could be alternative in the framework as well. Thanks for your experimentation. Sometimes letting control flow despite the error can have negative side effects. Thus framework approach has been conservative. Note, the exception here is not a problem, it is quite legit.